# Salary negotiation dilemma between established company and start up

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation, startup, title

So in past weeks there have been salary negotiations going back and forth between me and 2 companies

1. Company A(Promising Startup).
2. Company B(An Established Company.)

A little background:

1)Company A was the first one to offer with a bright salary X + 10K.

2)Though a few days later Company B offered with amount X.

in negotiations I made a little mistake of giving a range near 'X' but very shortly afterwards I had informed that though I was very seriously considering their offer but I have one more offer from Company A with X + 10 Amount.

The head who interviewed me with company B showed keen interest in me and sent some additional details on why I should work with them the work atmosphere e.t.c.

After a wait of couple more days considering that Company B is more established than A hence I reevaluated both the offers and came up with a number X + 5 for company B and little modification with the designation name 
to make it more precise with the job description.

Now with the company B with communication is via a Job consultant and he told me that it's very unlikely that they would increase though he also hinted at passing on contract from Company A with big salary.

Now I had responded to the Head of Company B with the proposed modifications of X + 5 salary and the precise designation name.

My questions are as follows:

**Question 1**

> I haven't got any response from Company B though it was just yesterday
>   and was a Friday. Do you think it was wrong to ask for X + 5 or in case 
>   they say NO I will evaluate the job offers again though not sure but
>   just in case I decide to accept X would it be unprofessional?

**Question 2**

> Is it okay to pass on the contract from company 'A' with higher salary 
>   as a proof that I have one more offer, so that they think I am not 
>   bluffing?

Comment: Please don't randomly italicize any part of your post, especially not large parts like you've done here. It just makes it more annoying to read.

Comment: You truly amuse me when you call the most important part or the actual *questions* as *random*

Comment: They are random in the sense that there's absolutely no semantic reason to italicize them. Similarly, they don't belong in block quotes, either, because you aren't quoting anyone. They were perfectly fine how they were in your first revision.

Comment: I completely differ from your opinion I would want to highlight to a person answering what he has to answer and hence highlighting the question is imperative in a long post. I totally disagree with you. Sorry!

Comment: *a part of?   I am assuming none of the jobs you^^^ have been through required written communication skills either@you amuse me[2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I haven't got any response from Company B though it was just yesterday
>   and was a Friday. Do you think it was wrong to ask for X + 5 or in
>   case they say NO I will evaluate the job offers again though not sure
>   but just in case I decide to accept X would it be unprofessional?

It would be reasonable to say something like "If you change your offer to X+5 I will accept."

Don't make that statement if it isn't the truth. Be ready to say "I accept" immediately if they make that offer. If they say "No" you could still accept - decide ahead of time which way you will go.

> Is it okay to pass on the contract from company 'A' with higher salary
>   as a proof that I have one more offer, so that they think I am not
>   bluffing?

If by "pass on the contract" you mean show them the written offer, that's okay. But that's not something I would recommend unless Company B explicitly says "We don't believe you have an offer."

Comment: I like this answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with bluffing, or at least using an offer from one organisation to elicit a higher offer from another organisation is that you had better be prepared for them to challenge your bluff.  Are you prepared to work for Company A?

If you are prepared to do that and to forego a role at Company B at the lower rate, then there is little risk to you for ask the question.  If, however, you would not work for Company A then you are quite possibly pricing yourself out of the job if they have established rate bands.

We can't tell you what to do, but you need to keep these points in mind as you decide.  It comes down to risk versus reward.  If you don't want the risk, forego the reward.

Comment: I wouldn't call it *bluffing* when I would say I am 'prepared' to work for Company 'A'. What I meant was the Company 'B' might think I am *Bluffing* if they ask for an offer letter form Company 'A' and I can't show it, which is not the case, but the ball is in their court they have to decide. The Company 'A' is rather a financial gain for me that also by a margin of 10K if Company 'B' refuses to budge.

Comment: Also a reason I gave Company 'B' that preposition of 'X + 5' was that though of course it's less than 'X + 10' but after taxes there wasn't a major difference in which case I was gonna decide for the established company that is 'B'.